# How to retrigger a webclient call based on the value inside response body

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have a WebClient that have retries:

```
webClient.retryWhen(
   Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(3))
    .filter(this::isRetryable)
)

private boolean isRetryable(Throwable throwable) {
    //TODO how access the response body?
}
```

Question: how can I evaluate the response body during retry?
Because I want to retrigger this webclient call when service returns http statuscode 200 and error message "failed" inside that response body.
or suggest me any alternate way to retrigger webclient call based on the value in response body?

Answer (score 1):

`retryWhen` is applied to error signals only, therefore you need to return error based on the deserialized body.

```
webClient.get()
        .uri("/test")
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(Response.class)
        .flatMap(body -> {
            if (isErrorResponse(body)) {
                return Mono.error(new ResponseException());
            }

            return Mono.just(body);
        })
        .retryWhen(
                Retry.fixedDelay(3, Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                        .filter(e -> e instanceof ResponseException)
        );
```